# Submitted Coverity build, see it running, then dashboard says "No builds submitted"

Tags: linux, gcc, coverity

cov-build version linux64-2022.12.2 on CentOS Stream 9 with gcc 11.3.1 20221121

I build with "./configure; make clean; cov-build --dir cov-int make". The tool reports 100% compilation units built successfully.

I've submitted via the web form and by using curl, both fail to show any analysis or error.